# how to access codeIsbn variable from outside the jquery keydown function

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you help me solve my problem

I want to get the value of codeIsbn which is in the jquery keydown function, then I will place it in the value bookCode

```
let codeIsbn;
$('#bookISBN').keydown(function(){
    let bookIsbn = $('#bookISBN').val();
    let splitISBN = bookIsbn.split('-');
    codeIsbn = splitISBN[1]+'-'+splitISBN[2]+'-'+splitISBN[3];
    //console.log(codeIsbn);
});
console.log(codeIsbn);

$('#bookCode').val(codeIsbn);
```

Html Code

```
<div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">ISBN Buku</label>
                  <input type="text" name="isbnBuku" class="form-control" id="bookISBN" data-inputmask="'mask': ['999-999-999-99-9']" data-mask placeholder="ISBN Buku">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Kode Buku</label>
                  <input type="text" name="kodeBuku" id="bookCode" class="form-control" placeholder="Kode Buku">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The error that appears in the console log is undefined

Comment: Can you include your HTML and the rest of your jQuery/Javascript?  Are you getting an error message in Chrome developer console?

Comment: of course. an undefined error appears when I do the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use keyup, rather than keydown.  Assuming the ISBN number should be greater than 10 characters this should work for you.  You will want to probably do something different to validate the isbn format and length. This isn't a perfect solution ready for production, but it's a step in the right direction.

```js
$(function(){
   let codeIsbn;
   $('#bookISBN').keyup(function(){
     if( $(this).val().length > 9 ) { 
       let bookIsbn = $('#bookISBN').val();
       let splitISBN = bookIsbn.split('-');
       codeIsbn = splitISBN[0]+'-'+splitISBN[1]+'-'+splitISBN[2];
       if( codeIsbn.length > 9 ) { 
           $('#bookCode').val(codeIsbn);
       }
     }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">ISBN Buku</label>
         <input type="text" name="isbnBuku" class="form-control" id="bookISBN" data-inputmask="'mask': ['999-999-999-99-9']" data-mask placeholder="ISBN Buku">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">Kode Buku</label>
         <input type="text" name="kodeBuku" id="bookCode" class="form-control" placeholder="Kode Buku">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```